# Show popover from UIButton

Tags: objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I created UIToolbar with a custom UIButton as child of the BarButtonItem in xib. I am using the toolbar as navigation bar in my application.
I need to show popover from the button, so I create popover on button action like this:

```
     - (void)showSelectSourcePopover:(UIButton *)sender
     {
       UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
       UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 400)];
       popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
       popoverContent.view = popoverView;
       popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(300, 400);
       UIPopoverController * popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                          initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];

      //[popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender
      //                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
      //                                          animated:YES];
      CGRect rect = [sender bounds];
      [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
```

But it is crashing without any error. I tried presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem function, but it is also crashing.

Comment: What's the error? *View* > *Debug Area* > *Activate Console*

Comment: Are you using ARC?  If I try your code in an ARC project, I get a very useful error message: "Exception: -[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible."  (In other words you're not holding onto your popover controller and it goes away when the method finishes.)

Comment: Yes, it was the problem. Thanks a lot.